# How to compare groups when the control group is 100 times larger than the group in question?

Tags: multiple-regression, chi-squared-test, statistical-power, large-data

I am working with NIS data which are basically a 20% sample of all in-hospital admissions in the US every year.  I have small group of cases that carry diagnosis "X" in their record and overall the only consist of 0.1% of the total n.

I would like to compare that group with cases "without diagnosis X". As you realize, with a total n= 6 million, the "diagnosis X" group is way too small for comparing associated characteristics against the "without diagnosis X" group (chi-square and t-tests, even regression)

Is there a way to control for this "overpowering" of the control group?

Thank you.

I use SPSS 23

Comment: Are all 6 million non-cases relevant to the study problem?  To put it another way, is X an "equal opportunity" disease, or are there certain risk factors for X that you can use to exclude non relevant observations? What kind of biases would you introduce in the sample if you do.  For example, if X only affects older adults (50 years+), you can probably exclude small children.

Comment: that's a good thought but X theoretically can affect all ages. I already excluded <18year old to limit the study to adults. Is there another way that doesn't have to do with excluding by specific variables?

Comment: are there risk factors for X that you want to test between the cases and controls?  My concern is that your study would be overpowered and you will find statistically significant differences that may not be clinically important.  Am I right in reading that you have 60,000 cases of X?  Is your outcome binary?

Comment: What exactly is it that you want to compare between the group with X and the broader population?

Comment: Binary outcome (in hospital death) with categorical and continuous covariates. Chi square and t-tests at first, then multivariable regression if possible

Comment: I have a feeling that differences in the group sizes make chances of a covariate being present in the small group statistically very small to show up in comparison with the larger group. Is there a way of somehow getting a random sample of the larger group of similar size with the whole smaller group X, and comparing them and at the same time being statistically correct/fair ?